# List<> of Dictionaries<> with unknown type

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a recursive discovery method, which will basically deserialize an object. This object is always a List of Dictionaries, but sometimes the dictionary will have other Dictionaries as values and sometimes the dictionary will have strings as values.

I need to declare the List at the beginning somehow. `List<Dictionary<string,???>>`

I am in a pickle at the moment, anybody know a solution?

Comment: `anybody know a solution` - Yes. Create a proper Data Model. Forget using Lists and Dictionaries for everything. Put Dictionaries and Lists where they belong and use a strongly typed object model when needed.

Comment: Sound solution, however the object is very dynamic and I cannot predict its structure very easily on my end.

Comment: Why not use `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` where object can be string or `Dictionary<string,object>`?

Comment: Sounds like an XML document, which is a tree-type collection of elements, each of which can contain other elements and also have name->value mappings (attributes).  So you could use the XMLDocument classes to hold this in memory.

Comment: I have considered this Rico, and at stage 1 I am already converting it in this exact way, however the point of the method is to discovered exactly what the value of the dictionary is, and considering this thing can be 8-12 levels deep, knowing whether a dictionary has another dictionary or just value helps.

Comment: Agree with @BenVoigt, this really sounds like XML to me.

Comment: I will consider the XML approach, thx for the idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically the closest you can come is probably `List<IDictionary>` (the non-generic `IDictionary` interface).

Given that the dictionaries can have different key and value types, you wouldn't be able to *use* them in a type-safe way at compile-time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the Dictionary<> in a class so that it becomes a List< DictionaryWrapper >.